# My daily backup crashed, how can I rerun cron daily?

Tags: cron

My daily backup crashed because a "bad" file of 30 MB existed which caused me to exceed by 25 MB daily backup limit:

```
-rw-rw-r-- rick/rick  29018177 2021-08-09 23:07 .config/mserve/ipc.pickle
```

I've removed the file but how can I call tell cron to run `/etc/cron.daily` jobs again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245056/200094) is close but you really want to use:

```
sudo run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

The linked answer omits `sudo` and my daily backup crashed again. This is because the same `.tar` work file (with errant 30 MB file) that was created with `sudo` privileges (which cron runs with) still existed.

I had removed the "bad" 30 MB file but the earlier `.tar` file created by the original `cron` job was still about. My regular user privileges simply were insufficient to recreate a new `.tar` file.

If you call `run-parts` without `sudo` your environment is different. Using `sudo` for `run-parts` makes it work. In my case at least.